# How to get the value of the dropdown which dropdown options come from the database?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have two dropdowns in my project. all the options in these two dropdowns come from the database. I want to select them. after I select them I want to bring a data from another table in my database.

In the normal situation the javascript could take the value of these dropdowns and with php code It can go to the database. But here because these dropdowns option come from database I don't have value so I can not take the selected items! I don't know how to do it. My question here is that How can I get the value of these dropdowns??

```
    <div class="one">

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Commodity Balance:</legend>
        <?php
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "dbtest";
        $usertable_commodity = "t_commodity";
        $columnname_commodity = "commodity";
        $usertable_country = "t_country";
        $columnname_country = "country";
        $usertable_mood = "t_mood";
        $columnname_mood = "commodity";


        $mysqli = new mysqli("$servername", "$username", "$password", "$dbname");

        if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli->connect_error;
            exit();
        }

        $sql_commodity = "select * from $usertable_commodity";
        $result_commodity = $mysqli->query($sql_commodity);
        $sql_country = "select * from $usertable_country";
        $result_country = $mysqli->query($sql_country);

        ?>
        <!-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
        <label for="Commoditylb">Commodity/Country:</label>
        <select style="border: 2px solid black;border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;" onchange="function1($stname_commodity)">
            <option></option>
            <?php
            if ($result_commodity) {
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_commodity)) {
                    $stname_commodity = $row["$columnname_commodity"];
                    echo "<option>$stname_commodity<br></option>";
                }
            }

            ?>
        </select>
        <!-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
        <select style="border: 2px solid black;border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;">
            <option></option>
            <?php
            if ($result_country) {
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_country)) {
                    $stname_country = $row["$columnname_country"];
                    echo "<option>$stname_country<br></option>";
                }
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        <!-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
        <?php
        if (isset($_POST['button1'])) {

            $sql_mood = "select * from $usertable_mood where (country='Malaysia');";
            $result_mood = $mysqli->query($sql_mood);
            if ($result_mood) {
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_mood)) {
                    $stname_mood = $row["$columnname_mood"];
                    echo "$stname_mood";
                }
            }
        ?>
            <!-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->

        <?php
        }
        ?>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="submit" name="button1" value="button1" />
    </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with all this code? Is this a JS problem, or a PHP problem, or a MySQL problem?

Comment: I suggest you learn to use a framework for that type of heavy binding between your database objects and the way you want to populate your forms with the data... Also, this will allow you to use MVC patterns to better manage your ui and your business logic

Comment: Where the values came from originally shouldn't make any difference to how JavaScript can process them. It's unclear specifically what the problem is. Maybe describing a specific example would help us to understand.

Comment: An example of what your database schema looks like might help with answers to this.

Comment: First, hide the 2nd (commodity) dropdown, after selecting the country run "function()". withing this function get the selected country/country id and run PHP code (WHERE case is country/country id ) with <select> tag.

Comment: @Lk77 Options do not have to have a `value` attribute. If it's missing the text portion of the option element will be submitted

Comment: Unrelated: don't close your `<fieldset>` before your `<form>`. `<fieldset>` should go inside the `<form>` (unless it's using a `form` attribute)

Comment: Unrelated: the `for` attribute of a `<label>` should point to an existing `id` of an element

Comment: @brombeer i'm removing my comments, so it's less cluttered